# Microsoft Identity reset password

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I am working with a Blazor project with Microsoft Identity.

This seems fairly simple, but it's not working for me. I am executing the following (NOT production code, btw - just trying to figure out how this works!):

```
        string token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(SiteUser);
        result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(SiteUser, token, NewPassword);
```

The result is `result.Succeeded` yet when I logout, then try to log in with the new password, I receive an invalid login attempt.

I've also tried:

```
        string token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(SiteUser);
        result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(SiteUser, token, UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(SiteUser, NewPassword));
```

But again, no joy.

How do I change a registered user's password?

See the github repo here:

https://github.com/lxman/BlazorPasswordReset

Apparently this is related to changing the UserName. Reference `ResetPassword.razor`.

If I comment out lines 21, 22 and 23 it works. But if I put those lines back in, it fails.

Comment: Debug properly! Can you give any remote access to your code?

Comment: Hmm, can't give public access to this code, but I'll work on getting up a Github basic example.